# Replace BackPropagation functionality of Keras Layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using the [yolo v3 keras implmementation](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3) and wish to add a [guided backpropagation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6806.pdf) module to further analyse the behaviour of the network.

Inside the yolo.py file, I have added this function in attempt to compute backprop:

```
def propb_guided(self, image, layer_index):
    from tensorflow.python.ops import nn_ops, gen_nn_ops
    from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
    box_confidence = self.yolo_model.layers[layer_index].output[..., 4:5]
    box_class_probs = self.yolo_model.layers[layer_index].output[...,5:]

    #box_class_probs = tf.Print(box_class_probs, [tf.shape(box_class_probs)], message="box class probs")
    scores = tf.reduce_sum(box_class_probs[0] * box_confidence[0], axis=2)
    #scores = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(scores)
    print(self.yolo_model.input.get_shape(), "input blabal")
    scores = tf.Print(scores, [tf.shape(scores)], message="scores")
    #grads = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.gradients(x, image)[0], tf.contrib.layers.flatten(scores), dtype=tf.float32)
    # gradients are the 1,1,w,h,c shape, c = 3 because RGB

    grads = tf.reduce_mean(tf.gradients(scores, self.yolo_model.input)[0][0], axis=2)
    grads = tf.Print(grads, [tf.shape(grads)], message="grad shape")

    # prepare image for forward prop
    if self.model_image_size != (None, None):
        assert self.model_image_size[0]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
        assert self.model_image_size[1]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
        boxed_image = letterbox_image(image, tuple(reversed(self.model_image_size)))
    else:
        new_image_size = (image.width - (image.width % 32),
                          image.height - (image.height % 32))
        boxed_image = letterbox_image(image, new_image_size)
    image_data = np.array(boxed_image, dtype='float32')

    print(image_data.shape)
    image_data /= 255.
    image_data = np.expand_dims(image_data, 0)  # Add batch dimension.

    # replace all relu layers with guided relu:
    # TODO replacing backprop layers doesn't work. The gradient override map doesnt work in this case
    @ops.RegisterGradient("GuidedReluBP")
    def _GuidedReluGrad(op, grad):
        #return tf.where(0. < grad, gen_nn_ops.relu_grad(grad, op.outputs[0]), tf.zeros(tf.shape(grad)))
        return 100000000

    tf_graph = K.get_session().graph
    layers = [op.name for op in tf_graph.get_operations() if op.type=="Maximum"]
    print(layers, "layers are")
    with tf_graph.gradient_override_map({'Maximum': 'GuidedReluBP'}):

        activation = sess.run(grads, feed_dict={
            self.yolo_model.input: image_data,
            self.input_image_shape: [image.size[1], image.size[0]], 
            K.learning_phase(): 0})

        return activation
```

Right now, the function gets the last layer (shape (?, ?, 255)) , and multiples the 5th filter (box confidence) with the class logits (filter 6 to 80, called box_class_probs). It then sums up a multiplication of all the filters and stores this in the scores tensor.

It then calculates gradients of each pixel from scores, with respect to some input image, and stores it in grads (grads at tf.Print has shape (416,416), which is the width and height of the input image).

at the end (where the comment is 'replace all relu layers with guided relu), I want to get all of the leaky relu keras layers, and replace its back propagation mechanism. I noticed that the keras leaky relu layer has a 'maximum' operation at the end, so I tried to replace each maximum operation with the guided relu operation I have made. Although this method does not work. Instead, the activation variable returned by this function has no effect, whether I implement the RegisterGradient code or not.

How do I replace the back propagation mechanism of each leaky relu inside some keras graph? This is so that I can implement guided backprop inside the keras yolo v3 implementation.